# Passing an array to another function

Tags: php, arrays

Hey guys having some problems with an experiment of mine basically I am trying to read a file then put that into an array and would like to use that array in other functions.

```
   $totalBand = 0;
   $weekly = fopen('filepath', 'r');  //opening my file

       handler($weekly); //Calling my function

       function handler ($weekly) {
              $dataFile = array();

          while (!feof($weekly)) {
              $line=fgets($weekly);
              //add to array
              $dataFile[]=$line; //pitting file into an array
          }
          fclose($weekly);  //closing file
          return $dataFile; //returning the array
    }

    function band ($datafile) { 
    //function for counting data from each line of the array from 1st function
        $totalBand = 0;
        foreach ($datafile as $lines) {
            $pieces = explode(" ", $lines); //exploding file
            if ($totalBand > 0) { 
                $totalBand = $totalBand + $pieces [7]; 
                //extracting information from the 7th position in every line
            }
        }
        return $totalBand; // total value from the file
    }

    echo '<p>Total band = ' . $totalBand . 'bytes</p>';
```

I don't get any errors but I also don't get a result and I know the info is in the right position and in the file I think it's my first function that isn't getting the job done namely the returning/ passing of the array..

Any help would be great!

Comment: From where are you calling `function band()`

Comment: What is `$weekly` after the `fopen()`?

Comment: If your function returns values - they should be assigned to a variable, don't they?

Comment: $weekly refers to the location of the file I am opening in this case it is a .log file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$totalBand = 0;
$weekly = fopen('filepath', 'r');  //opening my file

//Add this
$datafile=handler($weekly); //Calling my function

//Add This
$totalBand=band($datafile); //Calculating datafile

function handler ($weekly) {
      $dataFile = array();

  while (!feof($weekly)) {
      $line=fgets($weekly);
      //add to array
      $dataFile[]=$line; //pitting file into an array
  }
  fclose($weekly);  //closing file
  return $dataFile; //returning the array
}

function band ($datafile) { 
//function for counting data from each line of the array from 1st function
    $totalBand = 0;
    foreach ($datafile as $lines) {
        $pieces = explode(" ", $lines); //exploding file
        if ($totalBand > 0) { 
            $totalBand = $totalBand + $pieces [7]; 
            //extracting information from the 7th position in every line
        }
    }
    return $totalBand; // total value from the file
}

echo '<p>Total band = ' . $totalBand . 'bytes</p>';
?>
```

Comment: Should use `<?php` as if PHP is <5.4, and short_open_tag is set to false in the .ini, `<?` wont work.

Comment: This type of typo is understood Mr @MetalMichael. But, updated. Thanks.

Comment: even after applying these changes it's still not giving me a result and using            if (empty($dataFile)) {echo '$var is either 0, empty, or not set at all'; } tells me it's empty but I can get it working fine without the functions so could it be maybe I am using the wronf function for putting the info into the array?

Comment: To be pedantic.. you should avoid closing ?> to prevent any accidental white-space after the tag causing problems, but you're probably across that.

Comment: Perhaps var_dump($datafile) after calling handler(). Make sure it is outputting what you expect.

Comment: Maybe relevant: see feof() man page comment by Tom regarding foef/fgets interaction. He describes your structure as "A common (but incorrect) approach".

Comment: thanks for the tip Berniev it does indeed put out one big mess of an output but the information is there though it doesn't look like an array and trying to use    echo '<pre>'; print_r($dataFile); echo '</pre>';    comes out as undefined variable even thoguh I get data from var_dump..

Comment: After applying your changes silly old me made a typo thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You're not storing your result from the function *handler*. Or calling the function *band*. Need something along the lines of

```
$result = handler($weekly);
$totalBand = band($result);
echo '<p>Total band = ' . $totalBand . 'bytes</p>';
```

Could chain or do this as a one liner if wanted, but it'd look pretty ugly.

Might want to readup on [Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), as it looks like you're trying to access local function variables from the global scope. After the function has completed, you can't access the variables inside of the function anymore, unless they're declared globally.